# How to visualize data in a Django (real-time)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, data-visualization

The problem here is that, there are several options I can use in order to display real-time visualization in django. But which one of them is simple enough to be used in teaching a newbie?

What I'm trying to do is visualize data which is fetched from an external API.

Comment: If you are using Django to display real time visualization than you can use Django Channels https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/